# subquery return multiple records as object array to a field in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying this below query where subquery will return multiple records.

```
SELECT count(*) as total, GROUP_CONCAT ( SELECT `id`, `lead_id`, `transaction_id`, `status`, `created_at` FROM `payments` WHERE `user_id` = '7') as data FROM `payments`WHERE `user_id` = '7'
```

but it return following error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT `id`, `lead_id`, `transaction_id`, `status`, `created_at` FROM `payments`' at line 1
```

Please help me to resolve this

Comment: _“Please help me to resolve this”_ - then please do the bare minimum for making that even remotely possible. Please go read [ask]. No one here know what your data model is, nor what data you actually expect to get out of this. Also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/1427878

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the queries the other way around, e.g.:

```
SELECT `id`, `lead_id`, `transaction_id`, `status`, `created_at`, 
(SELECT count(*) FROM `payments` WHERE `user_id` = '7') AS `total`
FROM `payments` WHERE `user_id` = '7';
```

You can't return an array of records as one record in sub query. It's better to read the records individually and count them in the application (or read the count as another value from query).

Answer (score 0):

Why dont just simplify it?

```
SELECT `id`, `lead_id`, `transaction_id`, `status`, `created_at`, count(*) 
AS `total` FROM `payments` WHERE `user_id` = '7'
GROUP BY `id`, `lead_id`, `transaction_id`, `status`, `created_at`;
```

anyway what are you trying to achieve? give some sample data and data u try to get.

Comment: no sir , my requirement is to get data in single row